# Ajax iframe request only works once in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm using an ajax script to show a loading animation in an iframe while a php script runs. Once the php script finishes running the ajax loading script loads the finished php scripts output.

Update: I have resolved this by replacing:

```
url='action.php?run=go';
http.open("GET",url, true);
```

with:

```
http.open( "GET", "go.php?random=" + Math.random(), true);
```

I read that IE caches each request and doesn't like sending the requests more than once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/loading.css" type="text/css" /><div id="loading"><br><center>Please Wait...<br><br><img src="loader.gif"/><center></div>');
//Ajax Function

function getHTTPObject() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (E) {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        xmlhttp = false;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
//HTTP Objects..
var http = getHTTPObject();

//Function which we are calling...

function AjaxFunction() {
    url = 'action.php?run=go';
    http.open("GET", url, true);
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (http.readyState == 4) {
            //Change the text when result comes.....
            document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = http.responseText;
        }
    }
    http.send(null);
} 
</script>
</head>
<body onload="AjaxFunction()">
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide more information regarding the button code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` stuff before you test for the ActiveXObject. The latter is used for compatibility with older versions of IE (IE 5 & 6 I believe). However, newer versions of IE support the use of the **XMLHttpRequest** object. You might also try indenting properly to make your code readable.

Additionally, since you mentioned you're new to JS & AJAX, you really should look into using jQuery which makes using AJAX incredibly easy. I personally use jQuery as well as my own AJAX function, so, in practice, what you're doing is perfectly fine. But if you would rather do without the hassle then jQuery is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried moving the xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); stuff up as suggested but the result is still the same. It actually works once in IE, so the first time you press the button all goes well. However anytime after the first time you press a button (unless you close the browser) the buttons no longer work properly in IE.

Comment: Just wondering: What would this code look like if I were to use jquery instead?

Comment: I suggest learning the basics of jQuery and then looking at the API for the .ajax() function. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score -2):

Can you use jQuery? It has all the boiler plating for ajax you need in $.ajax